# Combine duplicate rows, merge and sum values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

I need to combine duplicate rows then concatenate values in column 2 and sum values in column 3, if row does not have duplicate retain values. I'm using Excel 2010.

Given;

```
Col1                 Col2          Col3    
Apple                Red           2   
Apple                Green         5   
24829                sk1           2   
24829                sd2           8    
123                  po3           1  
Bag                  black         7
```

Expected Output:

```
Col1                   Col2                   Col3    
Apple                  Red,Green              7    
24829                  sk1,sd2                10    
123                    po3                    1    
Bag                    black                  7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Google Sheets you could try:

Col G:`=unique(A2:A)`

Col H:`=join(",",filter(B2:B,A2:A=G2))`

Col I:`=sumif(A2:A,G2,C2:C)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use this one-cell solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A))), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY(""&A1:B, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)<>"", QUERY(""&A1:B, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 limit 0")&",", ))
 ,, 999^99))), ",$", ), QUERY({""&A1:A, C1:C}, 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0)})
```

[image: 0]